# Creation of GLCM texture images using MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, filter, feature-extraction, glcm

I am quite new to image processing and I have question concerning the use of a MATLAB function like a filter (`graycoprops`).

In the problem occurring is that I want to process the image using this function (`graycoprops`). To be able to do this I need first to create the GLCM (`graycomatrix`).

To do this for the whole image is easy but how can I do it for a small region (e.g. 3x3) like a filter.

I was thinking something like `colfilt` could work but I no idea how can I take each time the block values and feed them to the `graycomatrix` and `graycoprops`.

Any help would be much appreciated as I am many hours stack!!!

Comment: Is my question so difficult ? I think it is not as I see many examples of images calculated in this way ! I just don't know exactly the way to do it ! Please if someone knows give me hint !

Comment: Your question isn't clear. The GLCM is not supposed, to serve  as a filter, or to be filtered. In fact, the GLCM cannot be generated from portions like 3x3 square windows unless you generate one GLCM for each of these blocks. The GLCM is usually used to give you information about the image, not to represent a filtering domain. You can see it (and the graycoprops function) as a descriptor of the image. There are some techniques that use those statistics to uniquely identify a given image.

Answer (score 0):

### GLCM Code

You might be interested in the code I have on GitHub for [GLCM with sliding windows](https://github.com/palmerc/GLCM). It'll allow a lot of customizations and you can manipulate the windows size.